# Adding another route to API namespace in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have some routes under "/api" for example:

```
/api/users
/api/users/new
/api/users/:id/edit
```

In `UsersController` all of the methods response as JSON, and it behaves as an API system.

I want to add another route under `/api` namespace - like `/api/auth/index`

I added new `resources` but it not works

This is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: "pages#root"

  namespace :api do
    resources :user, only: %i[index show create destroy update search]
    post '/user/import', to: 'user#import_line'    
    resources :auths, only: %i[index]
  end

  get '*path', to: 'pages#root'
end
```

How can I add new routes under `api` namespace?

Comment: The route you added should respond to this url `/api/auths`.
What error you're getting?

Comment: yeah you are right. now fixed

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? Can you post the output of `rake routes` and tell us what you expect to be different?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `resources :users` not `:user`. Restful routes should mostly be plural*. If there is ever more than one you should always use the plural form.

```
namespace :api do
  resources :users, only: %i[index show create destroy update]
end
```

This might seem inconsequential but due to the convention over configuration nature of rails it will cause you tons of grief since it won't work properly with the polymorphic route helpers. The name of your controller should also be plural (`Api::UsersController`).

To [add additional restful actions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) pass a block to `resources`:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :users, only: %i[index show create destroy update] do
    get :search
    post :import, on: :collection, action: :import_line
  end
end
```

> How can I add new routes under api namespace?

By placing them in the block that you have passed to `namespace`:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :users, only: %i[index show create destroy update] do
    get :search
    post :import, on: :collection
  end
  resources :auths, only: [:index]
end
```

However this will create `GET /auths` not `GET /auths/index`. I would suggest you read the [rails guides on how the rails conventions handle restful routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

Comment: * There valid cases for [singular resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) but they are not as common.

Answer (score -2):

remove your %i and write like below, it's working for me.

```
namespace :api do
  resources :auths, only: [:index]
end
```